# I get a "no method error" using each to read a matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix, each

In a very simple program trying to use "each" I get the error : sum.rb:16: undefined method `each' for # (NoMethodError)

I get the same error using "each" various ways: the one shown below was copied directly from the Class:Matrix from ruby-doc.org.

```
# create State database using matrix
require 'matrix'

State=Matrix[ [3,1,4,4,6,2,8,12,6,2],
        [6,2,4,13,25,21,11,22,9,3,],
        [6,20,27,34,22,14,12,11,2,5],
        [6,28,17,23,31,18,15,9,18,12],
        [9,18,11,13,8,27,10,14,24,11],
        [3,9,7,16,9,15,28,24,29,21],
        [5,8,4,7,17,14,19,30,33,4],
        [7,17,23,9,5,9,22,21,12,21,],
        [7,14,25,22,16,10,19,15,12,11],
        [5,16,7,3,6,3,9,8,1,5] ]

State.each { |e| puts e }
```

This must be simple/obvious but I can't figure it out. (I've already done a variety of things with the State matrix that work out as expected.)

Comment: Everything works fine for me. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Andre, unfortunately I can't tell you since I installed ruby about a year ago and can't remember how to get the version.  I've also discovered that some methods work (e.g., det, row_size, col_size) while others don't (e.g., element).  Does your comment mean you copied the program and ran it without a problem?

Comment: From the command-line type: `ruby -v`.

Comment: @theTinMan answered it already, but yes. I ran perfectly on Ruby 1.9.3
It is very likely that you are experiencing version issues. Try upgrading your Ruby version OR look at your version's documentation to know exactly which methods are available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 will return the problem you are seeing. The Matrix object in 1.8.7 doesn't have an `each` method.

Upgrading to a recent version, either 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 will fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!  I would have never imagined it was a version issue.  I am in fact running 1.8.7.  Thanks.